# Problems with sails-auth-generator

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I am a newbie api developer working with sails js. I am trying to use sails-auth-generator for Authentication and Authorization. Here i am having some misconceptions. i have few question.

Say i have a user controller. For accessing an action in the controller i am using Bearer Authentication. So for this what does this means in the confid/policy.js file.

```
'user': {
    'remoteHome': ['passport', 'bearerAuth'],
  }
```

Is that matches the token only by using bearerAuth.js ? what is the role of passport here.